# Highlight active application in Gnome Classic taskbar

Tags: customization, gnome-classic, taskbar

I use (and love) Gnome Classic in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with the built-in *Radiance* theme. Only gripe that I have is that all applications in the (bottom of the screen) task bar are highlighted the same.

Minimized applications are indicated by wrapping the application name in `[...]`. Is there a configuration that highlights the active application in **bold**, or using a different taskbar button color?

#### Current

[image: original]

#### Want

[image: active app in bold]

[image: active app in different color]

Comment: I'd like to add a remark: it seems that this issue applies only to Radiance theme. In dark Ambiance theme (16.04 LTS) the button of active application is darker than the rest applications' buttons.

Comment: @whtyger: Thanks, that's a helpful observation! That means I could probably edit the Radiance theme to achieve the same visual distinction.

Comment: @whtyger Same with the Radiance theme on a newly installed gnome desktop environment. As I am not very familiar with gnome, I dont know how you got to customize the bottom taskbar. But my guess it the problem lies in the plugins to customize the taskbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing files `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/apps/gnome-panel.css` and `/usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-3.0/apps/gnome-panel.css` showed that one fragment in Radiance theme stylesheet is missing. We can copy it from Ambiance theme. Make a backup of `/usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-3.0/apps/gnome-panel.css` for safety and add these lines between `PanelApplet .button:prelight { ... }` and `ClockBox { ... }` blocks of the mentioned file:

```
PanelApplet .button:checked {
    background-image: -gtk-gradient (linear, left top, left bottom,
                                     from (shade (@dark_bg_color, 0.95)),
                                     to (shade (@dark_bg_color, 1.1)));
}

PanelApplet .button:checked:prelight {
    background-image: -gtk-gradient (linear, left top, left bottom,
                                     from (shade (@dark_bg_color, 1.15)),
                                     to (shade (@dark_bg_color, 1.3)));
}

PanelApplet .button:checked:prelight:active {
    border-image: none;
    background-image: -gtk-gradient (linear, left top, left bottom,
                                     from (shade (@dark_bg_color, 0.75)),
                                     to (shade (@dark_bg_color, 0.9)));
    border-color: shade (@dark_bg_color, 0.8);
}
```

This code is taken from the `gnome-panel.css` file of Ambiance theme. Reload and observe the changes.
These settings are adapted to Ambiance theme, but they'll work for Radiance theme also - now the button of active application will be darker than the other ones. Some adjustments of the values will probably enhance the compliance with Radiance theme, but that's the job of theme creators.
Created [bugreport](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-themes/+bug/1705034). Maybe it will be fixed in the foreseeable future.
**P.S.** Take into consideration that any update of `light-themes` package will revert this fix.

Comment: This works great, thanks a lot (and enjoy the bounty)! I've tweaked the styles a bit (e.g. started the shading from `@selected_bg_color`) to suit my preferences.

Comment: If others want to tweak as well: The first rule is for the button representing the active application, the second with mouse hovering over it, the third with mouse pressed on it.

Comment: Nice addition. I'll mention also that according to my comparison Radiance theme values are less than the Ambiance theme ones. You can safely decrease the values by 0.1 to fit better to Radiance theme.